# Declaration of MY_Email::initialize() should be compatible with that of CI_Email::initialize()

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Runtime Notice

Message: Declaration of MY_Email::initialize() should be compatible with 
that of CI_Email::initialize()

Filename: libraries/MY_Email_3_1_x.php

Line Number: 1374

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\e-com\application\libraries\MY_Email.php
Line: 17
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\e-com\application\libraries\MY_Email.php
Line: 17
Function: require_once
```

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\e-com\application\controllers\User_pannel_controller.php
Line: 478
Function: library

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\e-com\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

An Error Was Encountered
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: can you show some lines of your code?

Comment: i believe this error means if code is `init($a, $b)` then the other must be `init($a, $b)`

Answer (score 0):

It means your child class is not compatible with the parent. For example:

```
class CI_Email
{
    public function initialize($a, $b)
    {
        echo 'foo';
    }
}

class MY_Email extends CI_Email
{
    public function initialize($a)
    {
        echo 'bar';
    }
}
```

This code would cause the `...should be compatible with...` error because if you substituted an instance of `My_Email` for `CI_Email`, it would be dropping the required parameter `$b`.

Alter your child class' `initialize` method so that it contains all the same parameters as the parent class. You can add extra optional parameters, but you can't take them away, so you could do this:

```
public function initialize($a, $b, $c = 0) ...
```